# What is the motorcycle in this picture?

Tags: motorcycle, vehicle-identification, identify-this

I came across this image while looking for vintage adventure motorcycles and would really like to know what motorcycle it is. The place where I found the image as well as the several alternate places where I found the image while trying to identify it myself don't include anything about the pictured motorcycle. At best they discuss what the guy riding it is wearing.

What is the vintage adventure motorcycle in this picture?

[image: Unknown Vintage Adventure Motorcycle]

Comment: What does the sticker on the tank say - your image is not good enough perhaps if you go back to the original that would provide useful info.

Comment: Looks like a BSA B25 variant

Comment: @SolarMike I've update the image with a larger version but that's the best I've been able to find.

Comment: @Martin is correct. It's a [BSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSA_B25) and the B25 sounds like the likely suspect. Not sure which variant this is, though. You can look at the side cover of the engine (as well as the logo on the tank) and tell it's a BSA. The exhaust is aftermarket or specialty made. It looks as though all of the side panels have been removed and different fenders applied.

Comment: Note the gear change is on the right (and rear brake on the left).

Comment: it is a BSA possibly a starfire 250cc probably made before 1970.

Comment: Seems like this image came from the [December 2011 French edition of GQ magazine](http://blackandbike.blogspot.com/2011/12/magazine.html).

Comment: Could be a 350cc B50MX like [these](https://www.b50.org/foto5.htm)